# Inserting data to sqlite database using ContentResolver

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I'd like to use `ContentResolver.bulk(uri, ContentValues[])` method.

I have `sqlite` database stored under the database folder inside the app private storage. Database is named **mydb.db**

What would be the Uri to the table named BUDGET? Do i need to connect `ContentResolver` to my database somehow?

Comment: ContentResolver.bulk is used if you are using Content Provider. I dont think think you can use it for sqlite db operations. When bulk function is called ContentProvider's  bulkInsert method is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a content provider. Your content provider would then store the data in the SQLite DB. See the [Android docu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for details.

Comment: Is it worth using instead regular sqlite database ?

Comment: That depends on your program, content providers work nicely with `CursorLoader` or when you want to export your data for external use.